# Responsive <li> not shrinking to size of contained image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html-lists

I've never come across this problem before, have researched online but not found anything. I think I'm missing something fundamental here...

Here's my HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <figure>
            <img src="xyz1">
        </figure>
    </li>
        <figure>
            <img src="xyz2">
        </figure>
    </li>
    <li>
        <figure>
            <img src="xyz3">
        </figure>
    </li>
    <li>
        <figure>
            <img src="xyz4">
        </figure>
    </li>
    <li>
        <figure>
            <img src="xyz5">
        </figure>
    </li>
    <li>
        <figure>
            <img src="xyz6">
        </figure>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And here's my CSS:

```
img {
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
ul{
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
ul li{
    width:33.3%;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
}
ul, li, figure{
    margin:0; padding:0;
}
```

My images are all the same size. The problem is that my img's are all shrinking to a height of 344px, whereas my li tags are shrinking to 348px which results in a 4px gap at the bottom of each li tag.

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Do you have a working example of your code say in a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `li` has a bigger height than your width. Your actual image has the width and height of 195 by 195 (px). Because you set the `img` height to auto it uses the same width which is available.

**Example:** If your `li` width is 200 and the height is 210 the `img` width will be 200 and the height 200 (auto) leaving a gap of 10 pixels.

Your solution would be to set the height of the `li` to that of the width. If you were simply using a defined width in pixels we would set the same amount on height, yet because you are using percentage we can do this with jQuery on load:

**Edit:** The real solution is setting `line-height` to 0. Code has been updated.

```css
ul {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li{
  width: 33.3%;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

figure, ul, li {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>
        <figure>
            <img src="http://orig08.deviantart.net/630c/f/2013/230/f/9/sir_raccoon_esquire__dick_figures__by_jonathankrapat-d6io7ax.jpg">
        </figure>
    <li>
        <figure>
            <img src="http://orig08.deviantart.net/630c/f/2013/230/f/9/sir_raccoon_esquire__dick_figures__by_jonathankrapat-d6io7ax.jpg">
        </figure>
    </li>
    <li>
        <figure>
            <img src="http://orig08.deviantart.net/630c/f/2013/230/f/9/sir_raccoon_esquire__dick_figures__by_jonathankrapat-d6io7ax.jpg">
        </figure>
    </li>
    <li>
        <figure>
            <img src="http://orig08.deviantart.net/630c/f/2013/230/f/9/sir_raccoon_esquire__dick_figures__by_jonathankrapat-d6io7ax.jpg">
        </figure>
    </li>
    <li>
        <figure>
            <img src="http://orig08.deviantart.net/630c/f/2013/230/f/9/sir_raccoon_esquire__dick_figures__by_jonathankrapat-d6io7ax.jpg">
        </figure>
    </li>
    <li>
        <figure>
            <img src="http://orig08.deviantart.net/630c/f/2013/230/f/9/sir_raccoon_esquire__dick_figures__by_jonathankrapat-d6io7ax.jpg">
        </figure>
    </li>
</ul>
```

By the way, just to make sure, your post has the following CSS:

```
ul, li, figure {
    margin:0: padding:0;
}
```

Note `margin:0:` has a colon instead of a semi-colon at the end. Make sure to put CSS on separate lines to avoid these kinds of mistakes.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, but surely the li should shrink to automatically fit the height of it's contents?

Comment: @RichardTinkler I thought the same and I still do. I cannot seem to figure out where the extra space is coming from. I set the `line-height` of the `li` to 0 and everything (even the `figure` and `img`) had the same height and width yet still the spacing between persisted for no actual reason. I'll try to find a CSS solution, but for now this is all I have.

Comment: @RichardTinkler By the way please note that the `li` height will be set on first load, so resizing the screen currently does not reset the height to that of the width. Just throw the code inside of the on load function to inside an on resize function.

Comment: @RichardTinkler me again, setting `line-height` to 0 actually works! No more jQuery so no more "hacks" on resize or on load. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It may not make a difference, but it looks like your first li tag wasn't closed until the second to last line, could you move the last /li closer to the first tag?

edit: have you tried adding height:100% to your ul li selector?

edit: following Vladimir's suggestion below, you could maybe try:

```
.figurecontainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}


<div class="figurecontainer">
    <span class="item"><img src="xyz" /></span>
    <span class="item"><img src="xyz" /></span>
    <span class="item"><img src="xyz" /></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Rixcy. My mistake. Was correct in my code. Also tried the height:100% but no difference :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [flex css](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) property(you will get no problem with it)

Answer (score 0):

Remove margin from `figure`

```
figure{     
  margin:0;
  }
```

```css
img {
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;

}
figure{     
  margin:0;
  }
ul{
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
ul li{
    width:33.3%;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
}
li{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <figure>
            <img src="http://orig08.deviantart.net/630c/f/2013/230/f/9/sir_raccoon_esquire__dick_figures__by_jonathankrapat-d6io7ax.jpg">
        </figure>
    <li>
        <figure>
            <img src="http://orig08.deviantart.net/630c/f/2013/230/f/9/sir_raccoon_esquire__dick_figures__by_jonathankrapat-d6io7ax.jpg">
        </figure>
    </li>
    <li>
        <figure>
            <img src="http://orig08.deviantart.net/630c/f/2013/230/f/9/sir_raccoon_esquire__dick_figures__by_jonathankrapat-d6io7ax.jpg">
        </figure>
    </li>
    <li>
        <figure>
            <img src="http://orig08.deviantart.net/630c/f/2013/230/f/9/sir_raccoon_esquire__dick_figures__by_jonathankrapat-d6io7ax.jpg">
        </figure>
    </li>
    <li>
        <figure>
            <img src="http://orig08.deviantart.net/630c/f/2013/230/f/9/sir_raccoon_esquire__dick_figures__by_jonathankrapat-d6io7ax.jpg">
        </figure>
    </li>
    <li>
        <figure>
            <img src="http://orig08.deviantart.net/630c/f/2013/230/f/9/sir_raccoon_esquire__dick_figures__by_jonathankrapat-d6io7ax.jpg">
        </figure>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Ram. Did that. No difference :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you must try reset property in your code, which will remove default margin & padding .Try to put min-width of image equal to 100%
**CSS**

```
*
{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

img {
min-width:100%;
height:auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z7juhmby/1/